# How to Kick the User or Member from XMPPRoom

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, xmpp, openfire

I implemented the following code for kicking the user from XMPPRoom. I used XMPPFramework. See below code

```
NSXMLElement *destroy = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"iq"];
    [destroy addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"set"];
    [destroy addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_dictionaryStadium objectForKey:@"RoomID"]]];//stadium nam
    [destroy addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@",@"+923425623868",kXMPPHost]]; // user number.

NSXMLElement *reason = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"reason" stringValue:@"leave"];

NSXMLElement *item = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"item"];
[item addAttributeWithName:@"role" stringValue:@"none"];
[item addAttributeWithName:@"nick" stringValue:@"nawazish2"]; // usernickname

[item addChild:reason];

NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query"];
[query addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns" stringValue:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin"];


[query addChild:item];

[destroy addChild:query];


[kKXMPPManager.xmppStream sendElement:destroy];
[kKXMPPManager.xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

When sending a request I received an error. But I received an error, Ex: `service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>`.

Below are my sending and receiving request through XMPP.

**Sending Request:**

```
SEND: <iq type="set" from="abkcak@conference.mydomain.com" to="+923425623868@mydomain.com"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin"><item role="none" nick="nawazish2"><reason>leave</reason></item></query></iq>
```

**Received Request:**

```
RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" from="+923425623868@mydomain.com" to="+923472447462@mydomain.com/b228fc86"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin"><item role="none" nick="nawazish2"><reason>leave</reason></item></query><error code="503" type="cancel"><service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

Please let me know how can I solve the issues of kick user. I searched so many articles and implement those but all in vein.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever solve this?